# UWP scheduled Notification, Toast after app is closed

Tags: c#, uwp

now, I'm developing some notification app about the online contest.

image:
[image]

I managed to get HttpResponse, and parse it to my Class, and add my app as a startup program.

the problem is that I can't find a good way to How notify my app user.

yesterday, I founded Appointment class and I used it. but always, Appointment should be accepted by user's hand. and It is quite slow, and sometime it crashed.

```
 while (mys.Count != 0)
        {
            Contest contest = mys.Pop();
            var appointment = new Appointment();
            appointment.Location = "Codeforces";
            appointment.Subject = contest.name;
            appointment.StartTime = contest.startDate;
            appointment.Reminder = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

            var rect = new Rect();
            string tmp = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appointment, rect);

            list.Add(contest); //<- observable collection
   }
```

[image: Appointment halt] 
[image: Appointment halt 2]

so I changed my mind to use toast notification class. because I think it doesn't need to be accepted by user.

the main question is"

I wonder how can i push notification about the events which will be held in several days.
I mean

1. my App user just once execute my App.
2. my App Queried to website, and get some event.  (I did {1, 2})
3. for all appropriate event, I want to push all event to Toast Notification that is valid after my App is closed or my Computer re-boot.

I downloaded Karaoke one App from MS Store, and it pushes Notification periodically 24 hours, even it has no background process(I think), and even I never execute app after rebooting.
below image is Karaoke one App Notification.
[image: Karaoke one App Notification and Background Check image]

How can i Implement it?.

Thanks for read.

Comment: I think this is the typical use case of `Background Task`. You can set up a periodical background task which runs _in the background_ every 15 mins, to query the web service, and show the toast notification at the time of event. You **have to ask for request user's consent** before registering the task.

Comment: @kennyzx thanks. but I'm newbie, and i wonder it is possible following circumstance. 
1. user downloaded my app. 2. he can't see my mainpage.xaml, because my app is totally background. my app just use dialog ask for request user's consent. 3. every day, he reboot his computer and my background app start(do i need to use startup that i'm using?).

ps- i saw a documents from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly)
is this docs that you said?

Comment: Does your app have to be UWP and installed from the Windows Store? If you can use WPF then your requirements are much easier to meet. With WPF, you can have process totally running in the background, automatically started at reboot, and you can utilize the Toast Notification API of Windows 10, and you don’t have to write Background Task since the process is always running, so don’t need user’s consent (for registering Background Task) at all.

Comment: @kennyzx, Thanks for your kindness. I've just studied naive winApi(C), MFC, and UWP. I just skipped my studying about Winform, and WPF. I was in little-know state that WPF is more powerful to Windows than UWP... I really appreciate your advice, "use WPF". but now I'm in state of being familiar with UWP. you asked me why my App should be UWP, my answer is I think UWP is quite charming to me. Thanks,..

Comment: I c. You are welcome. Learning WPF should be a smooth experience if you already have a taste of UWP/XAML. Why WPF is more suitable for your requirements than UWP is that you don’t need to deal with the life cycle restriction of UWP - that it needs to launch by user and can be suspended/terminated by the system. Besides, WPF is a mature technology (with a history of 10+ years) that you can hardly find any question that hasn’t been asked before on stackoverflow, and almost the answer to every “can I do something in WPF?” question is “Yes! Definitely”.

Comment: @kennyzx, Thanks!.